# Emacs ESS autocomplete working in iess mode but not in scripts. How to get it working?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I recently started using ess for r. Emacs wiki shows that from version 12.09 ess by default includes support for auto complete. I am getting auto complete in the iess mode. But not completions in the ess mode. I tried setting completion to script only

```
(setq ess-use-auto-complete 'script-only)
```

but it did not work even then.
I also tried adding ac sources by hand

```
(add-to-list 'ac-sources
     ac-source-R-args)

(add-to-list 'ac-sources
     ac-source-R-objects)

(add-to-list 'ac-sources
     ac-source-R)
```

But to no benefit. Can someone please tell me what mistake I am making here? I am using GNU emacs 24.4.1 with ess  15.9.

Comment: Its value is t. And yes the R process is running. And I have added (require 'ess-site) to my init.el. Still no progress.

Comment: Tried this too. No change. Auto completion is there is iess mode, but not in ess mode.

Comment: Auto complete should work by default with no configuration. If it does not that means it is a bug or you have another source that takes precedence.  Please note that auto-complete support is not maintained anymore. Users are encouraged to switch to company mode. Company should work out of the box in script and inferior.